# nth-of-type не работает с числовыми значениями

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Есть вот такое огромное DOM-дерево сгенерированное библиотекой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хочу выбрать из него первые два элемента с классами `.tns-item.tns-slide-active`. При использовании любого nth селектора происходит следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но когда я использую не числовое значение в селекторе (например `odd`) все работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
C чем это связанно, и как можно исправить это?

Comment: добавь пример разметки разметкой

Answer (score 0):

селектор [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type), как следует из его названия, осуществляет выборку на основе типа элемента.

При использовании его с классами просто накладывается дополнительное условие: элемент с определенным типом не только должен имеет соответствующий индекс, но так же иметь указанный класс.

Исходя из этого кажется, что числовые индексы не работают, однако это не так, просто твои элементы не подходят под селектор.

Решением может стать только выборка всех элементов с классами, и затем из полученной коллекции получить нужные элементы с помощью javascript, например, преобразовав коллекцию к массиву и применив метод [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)